# how to show random values in textarea, such as every time page load it will show different message in a textarea

Tags: php, jquery

how to show random values in textarea, such as every time page load it will show different message in a textarea with jquery. i have a list of phrases and i want to load each phrase in textarea on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var quoteLentgh = quotes.length;
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*quoteLentgh);
$('#textareaID').val(quotes[rand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$strings = array("string 1","string 2","string 3","string 4");
?>
<form type="post" action="">
  <textarea id="box" name="box"><?php echo $strings[array_rand($strings,1)]; ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: You could also use `$strings[array_rand($strings, 1)]`

Comment: Ahh, didn't see you wanted it in jQuery. I'll leave this here as an option if someone doesn't want to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Ty something like the following (check syntax, haven't tested it).

```
var phraseAry = [];
phraseAry[0] = 'phrase1';
phraseAry[1] = 'phrase2';
phraseAry[2] = 'phrase3';

var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*phraseAry.length);
$('#myTextbox').val(phraseAry[num]);
```